# WSO2 IS 5.0 sp1 - Login error after leaving the login page opened for a while

Tags: single-sign-on, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 IS 5.0 Sp1, and I configured a SAML2 SSO enabled service provider.

When I open my service provider it redirects me to the login page in IS,
which is `/authenticationendpoint/...`, when I type my credentials and press login immediately after I was redirected to the login page, it works ok.

But when I leave that login page opened in my browser, and type my credentials and press login button, say 2 hours after I opened the page, the IS gives Authentication error message, with the following in the logs:

`[2017-08-15 08:18:56,260] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.util.FrameworkUtils} -  Authentication Context is null
[2017-08-15 08:18:56,260] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.util.FrameworkUtils} -  Authentication Context is null
[2017-08-15 08:18:56,261] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.util.FrameworkUtils} -  Authentication Context is null
[2017-08-15 08:18:56,261] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.util.FrameworkUtils} -  Authentication Context is null
[2017-08-15 08:18:56,262] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.util.FrameworkUtils} -  Authentication Context is null
[2017-08-15 08:18:56,263] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.util.FrameworkUtils} -  Authentication Context is null
[2017-08-15 08:18:56,263] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  Session data key  :  e6ef768b-4b24-4dbd-95db-b479a05535b7
[2017-08-15 08:18:56,263] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  Context does not exist. Probably due to invalidated cache`

Any ideas why is that happening, and how it can be fixed?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to session expiry. You can enable Session Persistence to avoid this issue. Please refer the documentation on [Enabling Authentication Session Persistence](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Enabling+Authentication+Session+Persistence).

Comment: Thanks for your response, but unfortunately with auth session persistence enabled as described in the link, still IS gives the same error